# datepicker hides after foucs

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, datepicker, jquery-ui-datepicker

I've 2 textboxes, `date1` and `date2` ('from', 'to').

When the user select a date from first textbox, second one should automatically opens (after first hides). I've set `$('#date2').focus` in first `onSelect` event; it works, but after second datepicker shows, it hides immediately.. check it [here](http://jsfiddle.net/dGRSC/)

What's the problem? and a solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Can't find an exact solution to your problem, but seems like some event fires that causes the datepicker to close. If you try and put the `focus()` call after a timeout, seems to be working (see [this fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/dGRSC/7/)).
I don't know if it suits your needs, maybe this could help you identify the issue that causes the problem...

Comment: Thanks. I accepted your solution; but I will look for exact solution for this problem.. maybe it's a bug..